# Webdriver-io Component not found after route navigation

Tags: reactjs, webdriver-io

*Scenario*: A visitor to my site clicks a link and navigates to a page displaying some text.

*Problem*: I'm trying to test if a component is displayed when a user clicks the link.

When I run debug, I see the component displayed, however, the test fails. Any ideas what I am missing in my test?

Thanks

## Component

### Home page component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import styles from './home-page.scss';

const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <div
            data-qa="home-page"
            className={styles.container}
        >
            <h2 data-qa="home-page-title">Home page</h2>
            <div data-qa="content-page-link">
                <Link to="/content">Content Page</Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default HomePage;
```

### Content page component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Content from '../content';
import styles from './content-page.scss';

const ContentPage = () => {
    return (
        <div
            data-qa="content-page"
            className={styles.container}
        >
            <h2 data-qa="content-page-title">Content Page</h2>
            <Content />
            <div data-qa="home-page-link">
                <Link to="/">Home Page</Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ContentPage;
```

### Content Component

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './content.scss';

const Content = () => {
    return (
        <div
            data-qa="content"
            className={styles.container}
        >
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </div>
    );
};

export default Content;
```

## Test

```
describe('content page', () => {
    it("should navigate to content page", async () => {
        await browser.url('http://localhost:9000');
        const contentLink = await browser.react$('Link', {
            props: {
                to: '/content'
            }
        });

        await contentLink.click();

        // await browser.debug();

        expect(await (await browser.react$('Content')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

`INFO webdriver: RESULT { message: 'React element with selector "Content" wasn't found' }`

Comment: What happens if you just get rid of that extra await in the expectation at the end of the test?

Comment: It throws an error, all Webdriver IO commands return a promise. https://webdriver.io/docs/sync-vs-async/#async-mode

Comment: Why do you need the double `await` in the end?

Comment: Because we're running in async mode. https://webdriver.io/docs/sync-vs-async/#async-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be a bug in the [resq library](https://github.com/baruchvlz/resq) that webdriverio uses. It seems it doesn't refresh the virtual dom tree for every search. A very hacky workaround is to force the refresh by resetting a flag called [isReactLoaded](https://github.com/baruchvlz/resq/blob/465ab5e3361da40f1b2752e15134cf9304efd972/src/waitToLoadReact.js#L3) before looking for the element.

```
        await contentLink.click();
        
        // force refresh dom after event
        await browser.execute(() => {
            isReactLoaded = false;
        });

        expect(await (await browser.react$('Content')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

Comment: I'll raise an issue on their issues board, thanks